TWRP loop on Samsung Galaxy A7
I tried to root my Samsung Galaxy A7 (2018) but now in TWRP mode, it shows with blacklines and automatically restarts. It does not even enter into TWRP boot mode.
Help me to get back into my mobile.

Which TWRP version did you install (link) and how did you install it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
